# How to keep playing online videos when screen is locked?

Tags: video-streaming

I want to listen to online videos with my mobile phone in my pocket, but there is always something to touch the screen and interrupt the stream.

The only solution I know is to download and save the broadcast or video on my phone before listening to it with a video player app which can be screen locked.

The issue is that I don't want to download any YouTube video before listening to it, so I'd like to find a way that can keep screen locked while playing a video.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use an alternative to the default YouTube app, a popular choice being [NewPipe](https://newpipe.schabi.org/). Although I haven't tested this myself yet, one of the listed features is being able to play videos in the background - even just the sound, without having to waste battery by displaying something you dom't actually care about.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution, if you want to listen YouTube song even when your android phone is locked. To do that you have to use chrome browser in android phone. Open YouTube in chrome browser and request as Desktop Site and search for the song which you want to listen then minimise it. The song will be paused then, from the notification you can tap on the play(▶). By doing this you will be able to listen YouTube videos in your phone even if it is locked.
I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can play a video on YouTube and lock your phone or minimize the app (in case you are using its mobile app) unless you subscribe to YouTube Premium. https://www.youtube.com/premium

Comment: Wow, I wouldn't have thought of that option... youtube app with premium ? That said I followed your link, and it says YouTube Premium is not available in your country... So it's a definitive no no. I don't understand why mobile developpers put such obstacles in the way of usability !

Comment: To make money. LOL

Comment: @user276692 That's because YouTube is sponsored by the ads and when you run videos in the background, the ads are less effective as the advertiser expects you to watch it and probably also interact with it. So, to protect itself (Google) and creators from lost revenue, and to stop advertisers from turning furious, Google does it.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox for Android had that ability. Due to Google making some requirements, it was disabled, but there's an addon which you can install in a second and that's all you need to continue playing YouTube in the background or when the screen is locked.

1. Download [Firefox for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox&hl=en)
2. Install [Video Background Play Fix addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-background-play-fix/).

Firefox should be able to continue playing videos after you have installed the addon and enabled it. Just to ensure that if your phone has a background activity manager (which kills background apps), you should whitelist Firefox so that it continues to work in the background.

Answer (score -1):

Try [Youtube Vanced](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-youtube-vanced-edition-t3758757). You can listen to any video while your phone's screen is locked.